# Functions not running when called?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble getting my javascript code to work. My goal with it is to be able to add new television series links to a database of some sort, and then open them all in seperate tabs when I click on a button. However, as of now, when I click the add series button, it doesn't save into the urlArray. Help?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">   
  function AddSeries() {
    url = getElementById('serieslink');
    urlArray = [];
    urlArray.push(url);
  }
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function clickyClick() {
    for (url in urlArray) {
      window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
  }
    </head>
  <body>
  <form> Series Name:
  <input type = "text"
name = "series1name"
id = "seriesname" > <br>
  Series Link:
  <input type = "text"
name = "series1link"
id = "serieslink" >
  </form> <br>
  <button onclick = "AddSeries()" > Add A New Series </button><br> 
  <button onclick = "clickyClick()" > Open Incomplete Series </button>
```

Comment: Your HTML is broken. Fix it!

Comment: Would you mind telling me what's broken? I'm not seeing it

Comment: There's a lot wrong there. You only need one `<script>` and you have to close it with `</script>` before `</head>` … Every time you call `AddSeries()` you first set `urlArray` to an empty array. Even then, it's declared nowhere, put `var urlArray = [];` above the AddSeries function, remove it from the function. …

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Looks like you copied it or something, do not post naive h/w questions or abuse this community. Check this updated code here: http://jsbin.com/gimewasimi/edit?html,output

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1- You should close the script tags.

2- You don't need to open separate script tags for sequential scripts.

3- You have to change the scope of the urlArray to global. You can do it by adding a **var** before the definition and outside of the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
var    urlArray = [];
function AddSeries() {
    url = getElementById('serieslink');
    urlArray.push(url);
}

function clickyClick() {
    for (url in urlArray) {
      window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you're not closing your `<script>` tags.  Have a look in the javascript console -- it should tell you something very similar.

The thing with JavaScript, in most cases when there's an error like that, it'll just stop evaluating any code on the page.